# Showing that $x$ is an element of group $G$ by left multiplication

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

**$G$ is a group and $H \leq G$ with $|G:H|=3$. Show that $x$ is an element of $H$ if $x \in G$ with $|x|=7$. Hint: let $\langle x \rangle$ act on $G/H$ by left multiplication and look at the orbits.**

Since the index of $H$ in $G$ is $3$ we can name the elements of $G/H$:

$1H=H$, $g_1H$ and $g_2H$

Except for the neutral element all the elements of $\langle x \rangle$ have order $7$ since $7$ is a prime.

$x^n \cdot H$ is a subset of one of $H$, $g_1H$ or $g_2H$

$x^n \cdot g_1H$ is a subset of one of $H$, $g_1H$ or $g_2H$

$x^n \cdot g_2H$ is a subset of one of $H$, $g_1H$ or $g_2H$

So far for my thoughts. I don't know how I can conclude anything about the orbits let alone conclude that $x$ is an element of $H$. How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The action mentioned in the hint gives a homomorphism $\phi: \langle x \rangle \to S_3$.
We must have $\phi(x)=1$, because the order of $\phi(x)$ must divide both $7$ and $3!=6$, which are coprime.
In other words, $x$ acts on the cosets of $H$ like the identity, and so $xH=H$. This can only happen if $x \in H$.

Comment: I don't understand why $\phi(x)=1$ if the orders of the domain and codomain are coprime

Comment: @Tracy, see my edited answer.